# How to rotate 3x3 2d array clockwise by n times

Tags: java

These are my loop statements. The first loop displays the non-rotated block while the second loop rotates and displays the 2d array by n(user input) times. My problem is that the 2d array will rotate once but will not rotate the third and following times around. I want my 2d array to rotate 90 degrees clockwise every time it is displayed.

```
        rot = x.nextInt(); //user input for n rotations
        //initial block
        System.out.println("1");
        for(i=0; i<block.length; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<block[i].length; j++)
                    System.out.print(block[i][j]+"\t");
                System.out.println();
            }
        //rotated block
        for(cnt=2; cnt<=rot; cnt++)
        {
            System.out.println(cnt);
            for(i=0; i<block.length; i++){
                for(j=block.length-1; j>=0; j--){
                    newBlock[i][j] = block[j][i];
                    System.out.print(newBlock[i][j]+"\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You keep rotating the *original* `block`. You need to rotate the block from the previous operation, e.g. by copying `newBlock` to `block` at the end of the `cnt` loop.

Comment: You are simply rotating the original array.

Comment: Besides, your code is doing transpose, not rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current rotation code is wrong AFAIK because you are just transposing the array.  Doing this twice is effectively a no-op because it leaves the matrix in its original state.  It should be intuitive to you that rotating a matrix by 90 degrees twice (i.e. rotating once by 180 degrees) should not, in general, leave the matrix unchanged.  Try this rotation code instead:

```
int dim = block.length;

for (int i=0; i <= (dim - 1)/2; i++) {
    for (int j=i; j < dim - i - 1; j++) {
        int p1 = block[i][j];
        int p2 = block[j][dim-i-1];
        int p3 = block[dim-i-1][dim-j-1];
        int p4 = block[dim-j-1][i];

        block[j][dim-i-1] = p1;
        block[dim-i-1][dim-j-1] = p2;
        block[dim-j-1][i] = p3;
        block[i][j] = p4;
    }
}
```

I adapted this in-place matrix rotation code from [this Quora article](https://www.quora.com/Given-a-matrix-represented-as-int-n-n-rotate-it-90-degrees-clockwise-in-place-In-place-means-minimal-extra-memory-to-be-used-ie-dont-make-a-new-array-to-copy-into).

Comment: I'm trying this out, and it works for `n=3`, but I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s and weird results for other values.

Comment: @mook I had one typo in there where a variable `n` appeared.  I have fixed this.  All you need to do is replace your current rotation code with this.

Comment: Ah, okay, I just assumed `n` was the number of times you wanted to rotate it...that would make sense that it worked for `n=3` since `dim=3` then!

Comment: @mook Each call rotates by 90 degrees clockwise.